# Java parallel stream - order of invoking the parallel() method

Tags: java, java-stream

```
AtomicInteger recordNumber = new AtomicInteger();
Files.lines(inputFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
     .map(record -> new Record(recordNumber.incrementAndGet(), record)) 
     .parallel()           
     .filter(record -> doSomeOperation())
     .findFirst()
```

When I wrote this I assumed that the threads will be spawned only the map call  since parallel is placed after map. But some lines in the file were getting different record numbers for every execution.

I read the official [Java stream documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and a few web sites to understand how streams work under the hood.

A few questions:

- Java parallel stream works based on [SplitIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html), which is implemented by every collection like ArrayList,LinkedList etc. When we construct a parallel stream out of those collections, the corresponding split iterator will be used to split and iterate the collection. This explains why parallelism happened at original input source (File lines) level rather at the result of map (i.e Record pojo). Is my understanding correct?
- In my case, the input is a file IO stream. Which split iterator will be used?
- It doesn't matter where we place `parallel()` in the pipeline. The original input source will always be split and remaining intermediate operations will be applied.

  In this case, Java shouldn't allow users to place parallel operation anywhere in the pipeline except at the original source. Because, it is giving wrong understanding for those who doesn't know how java stream works internally. I know `parallel()` operation would have been defined for Stream object type and so, it is working this way. But, it is better to provide some alternate solution.
- In the above code snippet, I am trying to add a line number to every record in the input file and so it should be ordered. However, I want to apply `doSomeOperation()` in parallel as it is heavy weight logic. The one way to achieve is to write my own customized split iterator. Is there any other way?

Comment: It has more to do with how Java creators decided to design the interface. You place your requests to the pipeline and everything thats not a final operation will be collected first. `parallel()` is nothing more than a general modifier request which is applied to the underlying stream object. Remember that there is only one source-stream if you do not apply final operations to the pipe, i.e. as long as nothing is "executed". Having said that, you are basically just questioning Java design choices. Which is opinion based and we can not really help with that.

Comment: I totally get your point and confusion but I dont think that there are much better solutions. The method is offered in the `Stream` interface directly and because of nice cascading every operation gives back `Stream` again. Imagine someone wants to give you a `Stream` but already applied a couple of operations like `map` to it. You, as a user, still want to be able to decide whether to have it execute in parallel or not. So it must be possible for you to call `parallel()` still, although the stream already exists.

Comment: Additionally, I would rather question why you would want to execute a part of a stream sequentially and then, later switch to parallel. If the stream is already big enough to qualify for parallel execution, then this probably also applies to everything before in the pipeline. So why not use parallel execution for that part as well? I get that there are edge cases like if you dramatically increase size with `flatMap` or if you execute thread-unsafe methods or similar.

Comment: @Zabuza I am not questioning the java design choice but I am just raising my concern. Any basic java stream user could get the same confusion unless they understand the working of stream. I totally agree with your 2nd comment though. I have just highlighted one possible solution which could have its own downside as you have mentioned. But, we can see if it can be solved in any other way. Regarding your 3rd comment, I have already mentioned my use case in the last point of my description

Comment: the _real_ question is: what are you trying to do? Since `Files::lines` does not really know how many lines that file will have, the only way it can process things in parallel is to batch. But the only way to batch is an unknown number of elements, is to start from some "default". In case of `Files::lines` the minimum batch size has to be `1024`, the next batch is even bigger _by_ `1024` (i.e.: `2048`), then `3072` and so on. So you need a very big File to notice any improvement from parallel processing a file.

Comment: @Eugene when the `Path` is on the local filesystem and you’re using a recent JDK, the spliterator will have a better parallel processing capability than batching multiples of 1024. But balanced splitting may be even counter-productive in some `findFirst` scenarios…

Answer (score 9):

> This explains why parallelism happened at original input source (File lines) level rather at the result of map (i.e Record pojo).

The entire stream is either parallel or sequential. We don't select a subset of operations to run sequentially or in parallel.

> When the terminal operation is initiated, the stream pipeline is executed sequentially or in parallel depending on the orientation of the stream on which it is invoked. [...] When the terminal operation is initiated, the stream pipeline is executed sequentially or in parallel depending on the mode of the stream on which it is invoked. [same source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

As you mention, parallel streams use split iterators. Clearly, this is to partition the data before operations start running.

---

> In my case, the input is a file IO stream. Which split iterator will be used?

Looking at the source, I see it uses `java.nio.file.FileChannelLinesSpliterator`

---

> It doesn't matter where we place parallel() in the pipeline. The original input source will always be split and remaining intermediate operations will be applied.

Right. You can even call `parallel()` and `sequential()` multiple times. The one invoked last will win. When we call `parallel()`, we set that for the stream that's returned; and as stated above, *all operations* run either sequentially or in parallel.

---

> In this case, Java shouldn't allow users to place parallel operation anywhere in the pipeline except at the original source...

This becomes a matter of opinions. I think Zabuza gives a good reason to support the JDK designers' choice.

---

> The one way to achieve is to write my own customized split iterator. Is there any other way?

This depends on your operations

- If `findFirst()` is your real terminal operation, then you don't even need to worry about parallel execution, because there won't be many calls to `doSomething()` anyway (`findFirst()` is short-circuiting). `.parallel()` in fact may cause more than one element to be processed, while `findFirst()` on a sequential stream would prevent that.
- If your terminal operation doesn't create much data, then maybe you can create your `Record` objects using a sequential stream, then process the result in parallel:

  ```
  List<Record> smallData = Files.lines(inputFile.toPath(), 
                                       StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .map(record -> new Record(recordNumber.incrementAndGet(), record)) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .parallelStream()     
    .filter(record -> doSomeOperation())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- If your pipeline would load a lot of data in memory (which may be the reason you're using `Files.lines()`), then perhaps you'll need a custom split iterator. Before I go there, though, I'd look into other options (such saving lines with an id column to start with - that's just my opinion). 

  I'd also attempt to process records in smaller batches, like this:

  ```
  AtomicInteger recordNumber = new AtomicInteger();
  final int batchSize = 10;

  try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(inputFile.toPath(), 
          StandardCharsets.UTF_8);) {
      Supplier<List<Record>> batchSupplier = () -> {
          List<Record> batch = new ArrayList<>();
          for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
              String nextLine;
              try {
                  nextLine = reader.readLine();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  //hanlde exception
                  throw new RuntimeException(e);
              }

              if(null == nextLine) 
                  return batch;
              batch.add(new Record(recordNumber.getAndIncrement(), nextLine));
          }
          System.out.println("next batch");

          return batch;
      };

      Stream.generate(batchSupplier)
          .takeWhile(list -> list.size() >= batchSize)
          .map(list -> list.parallelStream()
                           .filter(record -> doSomeOperation())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()))
          .flatMap(List::stream)
          .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
  ```

  This executes `doSomeOperation()` in parallel without loading all the data into memory. But note that `batchSize` will need to be given a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It is good to know about the 3rd solution you have highlighted. I will take a look as I haven't used takeWhile and Supplier.

Comment: A custom `Spliterator` implementation wouldn’t be more complicated than this, while allowing more efficient parallel processing…

Comment: @Holger Implementation details aside, how would it allow more efficiency (beside perhaps more knowledge of the data set, which it would in a sense be forced to have)? I can't imagine it having to deal with a different set of problems. I still think it's an option, though (except that IO APIs aren't my thing, personally...)

Comment: Each of your inner `parallelStream` operations has a fixed overhead for initiating the operation and waiting for the end result, while being limited to a parallelism of `batchSize`. First, you need a multiple of the currently available number of CPU cores to avoid idle threads. Then, the number should be high enough to compensate the fixed overhead, but the higher the number, the higher the pause imposed by the sequential read operation happening before the parallel processing even starts.

Comment: Turning the outer stream parallel would cause bad interference with the inner in the current implementation, besides the point that `Stream.generate` produces an unordered stream, which doesn’t work with the OP’s intended use cases like `findFirst()`. In contrast, a single parallel stream with a spliterator which returns chunks in `trySplit` works straight-forward and allows worker threads to process the next chunk without waiting for the completion of the previous.

Comment: @Holger Before commenting on that... 1. the last snippet has no place if `findFirst()` is the terminal operation (as I observed - first bullet point) - 2. If the number of elements is not high enough to justify a parallel stream, then the OP can also just process it in memory (second bullet point). -- Now regarding `batchSize`: my premise is that `doSomeOperation()` is slow enough to dwarf the overhead of those parallel streams. Beside that, with a carefully selected `batchSize` (one that minimizes inner streams), overhead can be negligible. A custom split iterator needs to solve for this too

Comment: @Holger But I'm with on the challenge associated with selecting a batch size that is aligned with the number of cores - although code can be written to take advantage of a different thread pool (assuming `doSomeOperation()` is not cpu-intensive)... And let me not forget to say thanks for your observations :)

Comment: There is no reason to assume that a `findFirst()` operation will process only a small number of elements. The first match may still occur after processing 90% of all elements. Further, when having ten million lines, even finding a match after 10% still requires processing one million lines.

Answer (score 8):

The original Stream design included the idea to support subsequent pipeline stages with different parallel execution settings, but this idea has been abandoned. The API may stem from this time, but on the other hand, an API design that forces the caller to make a single unambiguous decision for parallel or sequential execution would be much more complicated.

The actual `Spliterator` in use by `Files.lines(…)` is implementation-dependent. In Java 8 (Oracle or OpenJDK), you always get the same as with `BufferedReader.lines()`. In more recent JDKs, if the `Path` belongs to the default filesystem and the charset is one of the supported for this feature, you get a Stream with a dedicated `Spliterator` implementation, the `java.nio.file.FileChannelLinesSpliterator`. If the preconditions are not met, you get the same as with `BufferedReader.lines()`, which still is based on an `Iterator` implemented within `BufferedReader` and wrapped via `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize`.

Your specific task is best handled with a custom `Spliterator` which can perform the line numbering right at the source, before the parallel processing, to allow subsequent parallel processing without restrictions.

```
public static Stream<Record> records(Path p) throws IOException {
    LineNoSpliterator sp = new LineNoSpliterator(p);
    return StreamSupport.stream(sp, false).onClose(sp);
}

private static class LineNoSpliterator implements Spliterator<Record>, Runnable {
    int chunkSize = 100;
    SeekableByteChannel channel;
    LineNumberReader reader;

    LineNoSpliterator(Path path) throws IOException {
        channel = Files.newByteChannel(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
        reader=new LineNumberReader(Channels.newReader(channel,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try(Closeable c1 = reader; Closeable c2 = channel) {}
        catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
        finally { reader = null; channel = null; }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Record> action) {
        try {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line == null) return false;
            action.accept(new Record(reader.getLineNumber(), line));
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<Record> trySplit() {
        Record[] chunks = new Record[chunkSize];
        int read;
        for(read = 0; read < chunks.length; read++) {
            int pos = read;
            if(!tryAdvance(r -> chunks[pos] = r)) break;
        }
        return Spliterators.spliterator(chunks, 0, read, characteristics());
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        try {
            return (channel.size() - channel.position()) / 60;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return ORDERED | NONNULL | DISTINCT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the following is a simple demonstration of when application of parallel is applied.  The output from peek clearly shows the difference between the two examples.  Note:  The `map` call is just tossed in to add another method prior to `parallel`.

```
IntStream.rangeClosed (1,20).peek(a->System.out.print(a+" "))
        .map(a->a + 200).sum();
System.out.println();
IntStream.rangeClosed(1,20).peek(a->System.out.print(a+" "))
        .map(a->a + 200).parallel().sum();
```